# GCC can't find header, but KDevelop has parsed it. How to solve?

Tags: qt5, kdevelop

I am including a KF5 header (`#include <KXmlGui/KXMLGUIClient>`) and while KDevelop gives me info about this header when I hover the directive, GCC by no means can find this and other (very few and random) KF5 headers.

I am using CMake and I used the api.kde.org to find (and link against) every needed module for every header. I can't figure this out.

```
[  5%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/test_ktechlab.dir/ktechlab.cpp.o
cd /mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build/src && /usr/bin/c++  -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build/src -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build/src/test_ktechlab_autogen/include -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/ON -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build/src/core -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/core -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/drawparts -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/electronics -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/electronics/components -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/electronics/simulation -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/flowparts -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/gui -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build/src/gui -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/gui/itemeditor -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/languages -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/mechanics -I/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/micro -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/gpsim -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include  -std=c++0x -fno-operator-names -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts -Wformat-security -Wno-long-long -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Werror=return-type -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wsuggest-override -Wlogical-op    -fPIC -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   -fno-inline -o CMakeFiles/test_ktechlab.dir/ktechlab.cpp.o -c /mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/ktechlab.cpp
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/build'
/mnt/Volume_3/Gentoo/projects/ktechlab/src/ktechlab.cpp:12:10: fatal error: KXmlGui/KXMLGUIClient: No such file or directory
 #include <KXmlGui/KXMLGUIClient>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/test_ktechlab.dir/build.make:79: src/CMakeFiles/test_ktechlab.dir/ktechlab.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:279: src/CMakeFiles/test_ktechlab.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:144: all] Error 2
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The second line of your exposed build log contains the command to build your source. If you try every path given in the `-I` args (I admit there are damn many of them) and _append_ `/KXmlGui/KXMLGUIClient` - will you be able to find the file `KXMLGUIClient` file? (If you are a little bit experienced with bash you could check this with a bash one-liner.) If not then you know why the compiler didn't. (Btw. whatever your IDE might find or not find, finally it's only essential what `gcc` can find.)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the `-I` args too. I can't see the `/usr/include/KF5` which contains these headers. What is more mysterious is that GCC can find other dirs/headers under the latter path. I think some CMakelists.txt is responsible but I have included `XmlGui` under `find_package(KF5 ${KF_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS`

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware about this: Imagine you have set `-I/usr/include/KF5`. There is a subdirectory `KXmlGui` in `KF5`. In this subdirectory, there is a file `KXMLGUIClient`. Then, the following include is valid: `#include <KXmlGUI/KXMLGUIClient>`. The compiler will append literally what you gave in angle brackets to every given include path (the `-I` compiler arguments) and try to find a matching file until it succeeds (or fails at all). That's why I recommended to resemble compilers include search procedure manually to sort this out.

Comment: And btw. don't trust IDEs too much. Some of them are damn good but I did not (yet) see a perfect. They try to resemble what compiler will do but sometimes fail. The compiler doesn't consider any IDE "magic" but just the arguments which are given to it.

Comment: The above sample again: (I hope I don't bore you.) ;-) Imagine you have set only `-I/usr/include/KF5/KXmlGUI`. Then, `#include <KXmlGUI/KXMLGUIClient>` will **fail**. The compiler searchs for `/usr/include/KF5/KXmlGUI/KXmlGUI/KXMLGUIClient` which is (obviously) wrong. (Actually, it's quite simple what might not be expected from something complicated as a C++ compiler.) ;-)

Comment: All that is very good about how GCC includes headers, but cmake is supposed to do this for us. I can't understand what is missing. Documentation states that upon finding a KF5 package, it's headers are automatically searchable by the compiler.

Comment: "automatically" makes everything convenient but what if "automatically" is broken? You see the compile command (in your exposed log). It's output is there for a reason. It shows to you what all the "automatic" did or (accidentally) did not. The compiler doesn't care about any "automatic". It just reads its arguments and does what it is told to do...

Comment: If you think your CMake is broken... I didn't read your question that way. May be, in this case, you could make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to

1. Make sure you have included `XmlGui` as a component in your `find_package` command.
2. Be sure to add `KF5::XmlGui` in `target_link_libraries` for the target in question.

If you're wondering, why `target_link_libraries` affects your include path, you're not alone - but that is the way it works.

Comment: Thank you, I have come to the same conclusion about this. This helped.